# WPF Data binding: CollectionViewSource and ObjectDataProvider issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding, collectionviewsource, objectdataprovider

I have a MainWindow.xaml file:

```
<Window.Resources>

  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" 
    Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=DetailsCollection}}" />

  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DetailScopes">
    <CollectionViewSource.Source>
      <ObjectDataProvider 
        MethodName="GetValues" 
        ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
          <x:Type TypeName="entities:DetailScope" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      </ObjectDataProvider>
    </CollectionViewSource.Source>
  </CollectionViewSource>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="AccountDetail"
    DataType="{x:Type entities:AccountDetail}">
    <DockPanel>
      <ComboBox 
        DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=DetailScopes}}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Scope}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock 
              Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DetailScopeConverter}}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ComboBox>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
    </DockPanel>
  </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

...

<ListBox 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AccountDetail}" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=cvs}}" />
```

and its code-behind class, where I defined the filter for detail scopes:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        CollectionViewSource detailScopes;

        InitializeComponent();

        // Attach filter to the collection view source
        detailScopes = this.Resources["DetailScopes"] as CollectionViewSource;
        detailScopes.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(DetailScopesFilter);

        private void DetailScopesFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            DetailScope scope;

            scope = (DetailScope)e.Item;
            if (scope == DetailScope.Private ||
                scope == DetailScope.Business)
            {
                e.Accepted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, there's the `AccountDetail` class:

```
public class AccountDetail
{
  public string Value
  {
    get { return this.value; }
    set { this.value = value; }
  }
  public DetailScope Scope
  {
    get { return scope; }
    set { scope = value; }
  }

  private string value;
  private DetailScope scope;
}
```

Finally, an enum:

```
public enum DetailScope
{
  Private, 
  Business, 
  Other
}
```

When I run my code, I get a list box populated with a bunch of account details, each having its own combo box with a selected scope and a text box with the appropriate value. The problem is that all the selected values in the combo boxes match the scope set for the last entered detail and changing any of the combo box values updates all of them, as if they are all bound to the same account detail.

When I take out the `ObjectDataProvider` from the `CollectionViewSource` DetailScopes and bind it directly to the combo box's `ItemsSource` in the `DataTemplate` AccountDetail, the problem is gone. However, I do need it inside the `CollectionViewSource` because I am applying some filtering to it and I cannot apply filtering to `ObjectDataProvider`.

Could someone please explain why is this happening and how am I actually supposed to connect `CollectionViewSource` and `ObjectDataProvider`? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.

The problem with your code is that **every ComboBox is using the same instance of CollectionViewSource**; that means, the resource with key "DetailScopes" is **shared by all** ComboBox, so whenever you select one value from a particular ComboBox, it automatically selects the same value in all ComboBox. **It's because the underlying collection which is shared, keeps track of the selected item, and since it changes on selecting from one ComboBox, the CollectionViewSource notifies the change to ALL ComboBox**.

So the solution is very simple. All you need to make DetailScopes resource **unsharable**.

Here is the fix:

```
<!-- Please note this x:Shared="False" just after x:Key="DetailsScopes" --->

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="DetailScopes"  x:Shared="False"> 
    <CollectionViewSource.Source>
      <ObjectDataProvider 
        MethodName="GetValues" 
        ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
          <x:Type TypeName="entities:DetailScope" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      </ObjectDataProvider>
    </CollectionViewSource.Source>
  </CollectionViewSource>
```

Hope it solves your problem!

However, this solution will cause another problem. Let me quote something from MSDN, so that you'll understand what x:Shared does.

> ## x:Shared Attribute
>
> When set to false, modifies WPF resource-retrieval
>   behavior so that requests for the
>   attributed resource **create a new
>   instance for each request** instead of
>   sharing the same instance for all
>   requests.

Since x:Shared causes to create a new instance (a new copy) of the resource whenever you attempt to access it, that means, the Filter handler method is attached only to the instance which you get in the code-behind, not all the instances.

So in order to work your handler properly, you need to attach the Handler from XAML itself, like this:

```
<!-- Now please note Filter="DetailsScopesFilter" --->

<CollectionViewSource x:Key="DetailScopes"  x:Shared="False"  Filter="DetailScopesFilter"> 
    <CollectionViewSource.Source>
      <ObjectDataProvider 
        MethodName="GetValues" 
        ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
          <x:Type TypeName="entities:DetailScope" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      </ObjectDataProvider>
    </CollectionViewSource.Source>
  </CollectionViewSource>
```

Hope it solves all your problems. Let me know if you still face any.:-)

Oh by the way, the following code-behind is not needed anymore. So please remove it.

```
    // Attach filter to the collection view source
    detailScopes = this.Resources["DetailScopes"] as CollectionViewSource;
    detailScopes.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(DetailScopesFilter);
```

.

Comment: Thanks that did solve the problem. Also it caused another one: my filter is no longer working. It does get executed, but it appears that it is not applied to the combo box choices. Any ideas?

Comment: @Boris.... what are you trying to filter? Was it working before? Could you give me some more info?

Comment: @Nawaz: I've added the XAML code-behind class in the question body. It contains the filter that filters the `CollectionViewSource` DetailScopes. The general idea is to populate the combo box choices only with the enum values I want to, not all of them. Please note that when I am not using the `x:Shared="True"`, the filtering works as expected, but then I am facing the first problem you helped me to solve. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Boris... I've updated my response.. so please check it out.. and let me know if you still face any problem :-)

Comment: came across the same issue, thanks for sharing this tip! really helps.